# generate mouse velocity when only integer steps are allowed

Tags: python

I write a simple program in python which includes moving my mouse (I do his with [PyUserInput](https://github.com/PyUserInput/PyUserInput)).
However: It is only allowed to move the mouse in integer steps (say pixels).
So `mouse.move(250.3,300.2)` won't work.

I call the move function about 30 times in a second and move the mouse a few pixels. The speed with which I move the mouse varies from 0.5-2.5px/call. Rounding gives me 1-3 (move only want ints) which does not really represent the speed.

I search for a solution (maybe generator?) which takes my current speed (e.g. 0.7px) and gives me back a pattern (like a PWM Signal) out of 0 and 1 (e.g. `1,1,0,1,1,0...`) which yields the 0.7px in average.
However this generator has to be adaptive because speed is constantly changing.

I am quite new to python and stuck with the last point: The variability of the generator function.

Here is what I have so far:

```
# for 0.75px/call
def getPWM(n):
    nums = [1,0,1,1]
    yield nums[n%4]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is keep track of the previous position and the desired current position, and hand out the rounded coordinate. You could track the previous position in a function but it's much easier to do it in a class.

```
class pwm:
    def __init__(self):
        self.desired_position = 0.0
        self.actual_position = 0

    def nextPWM(self, speed):
        self.desired_position += speed
        movement = round(self.desired_position - self.actual_position)
        self.actual_position += movement
        return movement
```

Comment: after some adjustments its working like a charm. Thank you!